# how to combine object item and sum up qty - JAVA

Tags: java

i having an object with below information

TransHdr: id, order_num

TransItem: hdr_id, product_code, refnum, qty (child record)

transHdr.id=transItem.hdr_id

if let say 3 record can be found in TransItem,

parkA,112,10

parkA,112,6

parkB,113,10

i would like group it base on refnum, means that my result will be

parkA,112,**16**

parkB,113,10

i need a method that will loop the object (item level) and need to return transHdr object to other function. anyway to do this?

```
for (java.util.Iterator<ITransItem> groupTransItems = TransHdr.getTransItems().iterator(); 
        groupTransItems.hasNext();) {
        ITransItem _TransItem = groupTransItems.next();
        if (null!=_TransItem.getRefNum()){
        <question here..how do i group and sum up my item and become only 1 record?>
        }

    }
    return newGroupingTransHdr;
}
```

Comment: please clarify your question. I can't follow the structure of your object

Comment: assuming product_code and refnum is a pair: loop over the whole records and put each record somewhere (a list perhaps). if the record's refnum already exists in the list, add the qty to the corresponding list entry, otherwise add a new entry to the list with qty of the record.

Comment: You need to return a list of transHdr objects not a single object, don't you?

Comment: Hi Alex, i only return 1 transHdr with many item record. should it consider single object?

Comment: @ajenqong, Got it, you are right. It is a single object.

Comment: Are TransItem's from different TransHdr's with the same product_code, kept separate? i.e. in your example, if we add parkB, 112, 4. What would the solution be?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Map` with refnum as key and qty as value.

```
Map<String,Integer> qtyMap=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

while iterating, try

```
String refNum=transItem.getRefNum();
// Mark for removal ? if this is not the first item in the list with the refnum
boolean remove=true;
Integer currentQty=qtyMap.get(refNum);
if(currentQty==null){
   currentQty=0;
   // this doesnt exist already in the map, this is the first item with this reference
   // number in the list, so you should keep this without removing
   remove=false;
}
currentQty=currentQty+transItem.getQty();
qtyMap.put(refNum,currentQty);
// if the remove is true then remove this item from the list.
if(remove){
   groupTransItems.remove();
}
```

This will sum up the qty for refnum's in the map and once your iteration is over, the map will have the sums of quantities for each refnum. You will have to iterate the list once more to set the current qty to each item from the map [EDIT] :- Added the iterating time removal.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solution suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476616/554205). You can have a Map with ref_num as key and TransItem as value.

```
TransHdr transHdr; // Externally given
Map<String, ITransItem> collapsedItems = new HashMap<String, ITransItem>();
List<ITransItem> items = transHdr.getItems();
transHdr.setItems(new ArrayList<ItransItem>());
for (ITransItem item : items) {
    String ref_num = item.getRefNum();
    ITransItem collapsedItem = collapsedItems.get(ref_num);
    if (collapsedItem == null) {
        collapsedItems.put(ref_num, item);
    } else {
        int qnt = item.getQnt();
        collapsedItem.setQnt(collapsedItem.getQunt() + qnt);
    }
}
transHdr.setItems(new ArrayList<ITransItem>(collapsedItems.values()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish what you want to do is to embed the logic in an add method on your `TransHdr` class.

```
pulic class TransHdr {
    private String id;
    private int orderNumber;
    private Map<String, ITransItem> items;

    public TransHdr(String id, int orderNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.items = new HashMap<String, ITransItem>();
    }

    public void addItem(ITransItem item) {
        String ref = item.getRefNum();
        ITransItem currentItem = items.get(ref);
        if (currentItem == null) {
            items.put(ref, item);
        } else {
            int qnt = item.getQnt();
            currentItem.setQnt(currentItem.getQnt() + qnt);
        }
    }

    public Set<ITransItem> getItems() {
        return items.values();
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's multiple ways of doing this. The appropriate solution depends on what your requirements and use cases are.